# Android AlarmManager Pause/Continue

Tags: java, android

I want to make an application that reminds the user to drink water every hour.  I want to send notifications every hour but I want to pause the alarmmanager (notification) at night time and resume/continue in the morning. How can I do this?

Comment: Check this link may be help you out. https://en.proft.me/2017/05/7/scheduling-operations-alarmmanager-android/

Comment: I already know these. I want to ask; each time the repeating alarm will stop at night and want to continue the morning

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Time when the alarm triggered.

Get the calendar instance in your BroadcastReceiever, and do startForegroundService

on the limited time that you wanted.

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    val service = Intent(context, NotificationService::class.java)
    service.putExtra("reason", intent!!.getIntExtra("reason", 0))
    service.putExtra("timestamp", intent.getLongExtra("timestamp", 0))
    service.putExtra("items", intent.getIntExtra("items", 0))

    when (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR)) {

        // do push from 8 to 24
        in 8..24 -> {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    context!!.startForegroundService(service)
                } else {
                    context!!.startService(service)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm already checking this before you start the alarm.  The alarm repeats once every hour.  I just want it to stop at 12 pm (not sending notifications) to run again at 8 am in the morning (sending notifications). Thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

I want to mute repetitive alarms during sleep time

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.remind.drink.water.hourly